# Why for-in loop for dictionary not sequential

Tags: swift

Why **for-in loop** for dictionary is not sequential

```
let numberOfLegs = ["spider": 8, "ant": 6, "cat": 4]
for (animalName, legCount) in numberOfLegs {
    print("\(animalName)s have \(legCount) legs")
}
```

OutPut.

```
ants have 6 legs
spiders have 8 legs
cats have 4 legs
```

Comment: Because Dictionaries are associative collections with no defined ordering to their elements.

Comment: I should not that it's not because of the `for` loop. Any method of iteration (manually incrementing the dictionary's indexes, `makeIterator()` + `next()`, etc.) would have the same non deterministic ordering.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexander said in his comment, dictionaries are unordered collections. They don't have any specific order to them. If you want ordering, use an array of structs. Arrays *do* preserve order.

Comment: Thanks Duncan I agree to Alex comments

Answer (score 0):

If you <kbd>option</kbd>-click on `Dictionary`, the pop-up tells you in great detail about the `Dictionary`.

Three key points from Apple's documentation:

> 1. Every dictionary is **an unordered collection of key-value pairs**.
> 2. The order of key-value pairs in a dictionary is stable between mutations but is otherwise unpredictable.
> 3. If you need an ordered collection of key-value pairs and don’t need the fast key lookup that Dictionary provides, see the
>      `KeyValuePairs` type for an alternative.

<kbd>option</kbd>-click on `KeyValuePairs` yields (I added the numbering):

> 1. Use a `KeyValuePairs` instance when you need **an ordered collection of
>      key-value pairs** and don’t require the fast key lookup that the
>      `Dictionary` type provides.
> 2. Unlike key-value pairs in a true dictionary,
>      neither the key nor the value of a `KeyValuePairs` instance must conform
>      to the `Hashable` protocol.
> 3. You initialize a `KeyValuePairs` instance
>      using a Swift dictionary literal.
> 4. Besides maintaining the order of the
>      original dictionary literal, `KeyValuePairs` also allows duplicates
>      keys.

Here is your example using `KeyValuePairs`:

```
let numberOfLegs: KeyValuePairs = ["spider": 8, "ant": 6, "cat": 4]

// Now this gives the order you expect
for (animalName, legCount) in numberOfLegs {
    print("\(animalName)s have \(legCount) legs")
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> spiders have 8 legs
> ants have 6 legs
> cats have 4 legs
> ```

```
// But KeyValuePairs cannot be used for fast key lookup like a Dictionary
// If you don't have duplicate keys, you can convert the KeyValuePairs
// to Dictionary like this for normal lookup operations
let numberOfLegsDict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: numberOfLegs.map {(key: $0, value: $1)})
```

**Note:** `KeyValuePairs` was called `DictionaryLiteral` in Swift 4.2 and earlier versions.

Comment: What a nice find 